# How to keep track real time points changing?

Tags: sql-server, real-time

I am doing a membership system where members are allow to earn and use points. Some of the points are also having expiry date.

Currently my system is having 3 db tables.

1) Member table with personal details and a column to store total point of the member.

2) Transaction table to store points earn and expiry date(if there is one)

3) Point usage table to store record of how many points being used, maybe use to buy goods from my site (each use per row)

I am having a hard time identifying which points is being used before it expired or is it just expired.

So I hope I can get some suggestion or advice here. Or is it any problem with my db table design that cause me this problem?

Update:
And is it good to keep updating the total point column in member table once member earn or use point, will this make the system do extra work?

Comment: You should create a link table between the purchase table and the earnings table, detailing which point earnings where used when you make a purchase, and how many of those points were used. Additionally, you should ensure points only expire at midnight. To find out how many points the user has on a date, find all earnings in range and subtract the points spent from each.

Comment: If the total amount of used points is smaller than the total amount of points at the date of expiry, then the points have expired (and probably can also be a partly usage & expiry). If the amount of data isn't huge, it shouldn't be that heavy operation to calculate that for each expiry date.

Comment: @Laase V. karlsen, do you mean by having a table recording from which earning is this used point from? Means that everytime I will need to look for the oldest non expired transaction and check if this earning is enough for the usage, and store maybe the id of this transaction and how many point used from this transaction? How about if I used points from 2 earning record? Do I create 2 row for this link table?

Comment: @JamesZ, do u suggest to recalculate all records everytime before the member use the point? The operation would be heavy since member is going to earn only a few points for every real time action they do so the earning record will be massive.

Comment: If the only problem is "identifying which points is being used before it expired or is it just expired" you could just add used ponts column into the table and then you see if they are used or expired

Comment: So for everytime member use point or a schedule job run to "expire" points, will need to update this used point column, right?

Answer (score 0):

I 'm not sure I understand exactly what you need but I come up with something like this:

```
create table UserPoints(

    Id int not null identity( 1, 1 ),
    UserId int not null,
    Points int not null,
    [Date] datetime2( 3 ) not null,
    ExpireDate datetime2( 3 ) null

)
Go

-- + for earning points
-- - for loosing points
Insert into UserPoints Values
( 1,10,getdate(), null ),
( 1,10,dateadd(hour,1,getdate()), null ),
( 1,100,dateadd(month,2,getdate()), '2016-04-02' ),
( 1,-15,dateadd(month,3,getdate()), null ),
( 1,30,dateadd(month,4,getdate()), null )
Go


select * from UserPoints  order by [date]

--declare @checkDate datetime2(3) = '2016-04-02'
--declare @checkDate datetime2(3) = '2016-04-02 10:00'
declare @checkDate datetime2(3) = '2016-04-03'

select
    sum( points ) as 'UserPointsAtSpecificDate'
from
    UserPoints
where
    ( UserId = 1 )
    and ( [date] <= @checkDate )
    and ( isnull( expireDate, '9999-12-31' ) >= @checkDate )
```

Comment: Does this means that if the point expire, will need to insert a record of -[point] into the table? But how can you make sure the point is expired or already being used?

Comment: No. With this structure you can get the running points of the user at any given date and time. If I understood correctly you want to know at a loosing/using points events IF he was using not yet expired points, and in case that he did HOW MANY points he was using at that time. Correct?

Comment: Sorry, I think it was my bad description. But what I want is to keep track total points available for member starting from when they join until future. Meanwhile, ensure that member will not be using expired points and the system will not "expired" the used point. Hope this clarify my question.